# Why does lambda translation need generation of a static method?

Tags: java, lambda, jvm, java-8, bytecode

Lambda translation is a two step process, **One**: desugaring the lambda into a static method in same class.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = () -> System.out.println("Hello");
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(Main.class.getDeclaredMethods()));
    }
}
```

> [**private static void Main.lambda$main$0()**, public static void
>   Main.main(java.lang.String[])]

**Two**: generation of a class that implements the Functional Interface.

```
System.out.println("A class has been generated: " + r.getClass());
System.out.println("That implements a Functional Interface: " + Arrays.asList(r.getClass().getInterfaces()));
```

> A class has been generated: class Main$$Lambda$1/149928006
>
> That implements a Functional Interface: [interface java.lang.Runnable]

**Question**: **What is the need of this static method?** Why can't the lambda body be put directly into the interface method? Something like:

```
class Main$$Lambda$1 {
    public void run() {
        /* Lambda body here */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In addition to the correct answers given here (because the current scheme is more efficient, reducing capture/linkage costs for lambdas and reducing code duplication), there are a few other reasons why your idea simply doesn't make sense.

- Where would the bytecode come from in the first place?  The lambda proxy class is generated at runtime, not compile time.  If we were to stuff the bytecode into the proxy class, it would have to come from somewhere.  That would mean we'd have to put it into the capturing class file *and then copy* it into the proxy class.  Here, it just lives in the capturing class and we're done.
- Access control.  What if the lambda body calls a private method?  By desugaring it into the capturing class, it automatically acquires the access control context of the capturing class (which it is logically a part of.)  If we put the bytecode in the proxy class, we'd have to do additional magic to give it the right access control context.

Comment: Ironically, the generated proxy class *needs* this “additional magic” even if the lambda expression doesn’t use `private` features as the generated method holding the lambda’s body is itself `private`. However, it’s still easier to retain the scoping rules if the interface instance itself is not in scope. Think of `super` calls, etc.

Answer (score 9):

Because this way it's actually cheaper. Generating a lambda from the method on the fly during the first invocation is better than loading a separate class via class loader. Internally it uses `UNSAFE.defineAnonymousClass` which is more light-weight class than normal. Such "lambda-class" is not bound to any class loader, so can be easily garbage-collected when it's no longer necessary. Also I guess there are plans to make this mechanism even more light-weight and faster. For normal anonymous class this would not be possible as from the point of JVM such classes don't differ from usual classes and much more heavy.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more? I can't understand `better than loading a separate class`. A class would need to be generated in any case to implement the functional interface. What separate class are you talking about?

Comment: `For normal anonymous class` I'm not advocating implementing lambdas using anonymous inner classes. Let them be implemented using lightweight magic classes. But directly add the lambda code into them. I assume these special classes can hold code inside.

Comment: Suppose that we should create `class Main$$Lambda$1` as you suggest. Then we should create the separate .class file next to your `Main` class (probably in the same JAR or so). So this class file is what I mean by "separate class". This is a normal class which exists before the application starts and should be loaded by JVM as a normal class. But lambda-class does not exist on your hard drive and generated on the fly during runtime.

Comment: So the question is where to put the code of your lambda function body after the javac compilation but before your application starts. The current solution is to store it as a separate method in the class where lambda is defined. Which alternative do you suggest?

Comment: That makes sense. `LambdaMetafactory.metafactory()` needs a `MethodHandle` to an method that provides lambda code. And this handle must be to an independent method, you can't link to the middle of a method. Am I getting this right?

Comment: Are classes generated during runtime not subject to bytecode verification? Is that why they're lightweight?

Answer (score 3):

Your test is incomplete.

```
public class Lambda {

  private String hello = "Hello from instance";

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Runnable r = () -> System.out.println("Hello");
    for (Method m: Lambda.class.getDeclaredMethods()) {
      System.out.println(m);
    }
  }

  public void instanceMethodWithAccessToInstanceVariables(){
    Runnable r = () -> System.out.println(hello);
  }

  public void instanceMethodWithoutAccessToInstanceVariables(){
    Runnable r = () -> System.out.println("Hello from instance");
  }
}
```

This results in the following:

```
public void Lambda.instanceMethodWithAccessToInstanceVariables()
public void Lambda.instanceMethodWithoutAccessToInstanceVariables()
private static void Lambda.lambda$instanceMethodWithoutAccessToInstanceVariables$2()
private void Lambda.lambda$instanceMethodWithAccessToInstanceVariables$1()
private static void Lambda.lambda$main$0()
public static void Lambda.main(java.lang.String[])
```

This clearly shows several cases:

- lambdas in static method declare static method
- lambdas in instance methods using instance variables declare instance methods
- lambdas in instance methods not using instance variables declare static method

The two first are rather logical. Why would you expect a static member to access an instance member? Same for the instance method.

The real question is why does an instance method not using any instance variables declare a static method?

Well, this is also for performance and safety reasons mentioned by Tagir.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding it right but this doesn't address my question. Why generate any methods at all? Why not move lambda bodies into generated classes.

Comment: That is simply to keep the scope of variables and accesses identical.